# How to store each button click in an array-andoid

Tags: android, arrays

I'm tasked with having 5 questions and each question contain 5 options button(Answers).When I pressed one option(button) that value should store in an array with corresponding question option.when i pressed next button the same procedure is taking place till 5 question.i want to store question and corresponding answer in each array

```java
public void onClick (View v) {
    case R.id.btnForword:
        Log.i("Count Value", "" + count);
        if (count < str_Q_QuestionArray.length - 1) {
            count = count + 1;
            tvQuestion.setText("" + (count + 1) + ". "
                    + str_Q_QuestionArray[count]);

            btnOpt_1.setText(str_Opt1[count]);
            btnOpt_2.setText(str_Opt2[count]);
            btnOpt_3.setText(str_Opt3[count]);
            btnOpt_4.setText(str_Opt4[count]);
            btnOpt_5.setText(str_Opt5[count]);

            Log.i("Count Value", "" + count);

        } else {
            Intent intFeedEmail = new Intent(Feedback.this,
                    FeedBack_Email.class);
            startActivity(intFeedEmail);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btnPrevious:
        Log.i("Count Value", "" + count);
        String countTxt = "" + count;

        if (count == 0) {
            Log.i("Nothing to do ", "" + count);
        } else {
            count = count - 1;
            tvQuestion.setText(countTxt + ". " + str_Q_QuestionArray[count]);
            btnOpt_1.setText(str_Opt1[count]);
            btnOpt_2.setText(str_Opt2[count]);
            btnOpt_3.setText(str_Opt3[count]);
            btnOpt_4.setText(str_Opt4[count]);
            btnOpt_5.setText(str_Opt5[count]);
            Log.i("Count Value ::::", "" + count);
        }
        break;

    case R.id.opn1:
        btnOpt_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_toggle_blue);
        btnOpt_1.setEnabled(false);
        String excellent=btnOpt_1.getText().toString();
        break;
    .
    .
    .
    case R.id.opn5:
        btnOpt_5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_toggle_blue);
        btnOpt_5.setEnabled(false);
        String bad=btnOpt_2.getText().toString();
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt understand the question fully but maybe this would make sense

create a Class that keeps the question and answer in 2 variables 
for example the class name QA.
create the Array from with class

```
 QA[] = new QA[5];
```

this would be basicly give you the location to save the Q&A
when you finish the quiz you can just loop over the Array and display the Q&A

am i close?

Hope it helps.